# Error 'can't assign to operator' when trying to assign to a string I create in-place at the same time

Tags: python, string, syntax, syntax-error, assign

I am trying to run this code:

```
from crontab import CronTab
import pandas as pd
cron = CronTab(user='bla')

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt')

def func_assign_job(row):
    '''A function executed on each row of the df dataframe.
    I want for each row the job string to be unique'''    
    'job_'+str(row.name)+str(row.time) = cron.new(command='python crontab_example1.py')
    'job_'+str(row.name)+str(row.time).setall('55 16 * * *')

df.apply(func_assign_job, axis=1)
```

At the line

```
'job_'+str(row.name)+str(row.time) = cron.new(command='python crontab_example1.py')
```

I get the error-message **"SyntaxError: can't assign to operator"**. I understand what's the problem - I am trying to assign something to a string I am creating in-place at the same time. I do this, because I need to have the actions in the function assigned to different strings, depending on the input of the function, e.g. assigned to `job_John_08:00`, `job_Mila_11:00` a.s.o. For example, this code would work:

```
job_name = cron.new(command='python crontab_example1.py')
job_name.setall('55 16 * * *')
```

but I don't want to use `job_name`, because I want this string to be different for each row.

**So, how can I achieve this goal of mine? What workarounds are there?** tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [dict](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp) to manage your functions with custom names? Something like that.

```
from crontab import CronTab
import pandas as pd
cron = CronTab(user='bla')

df = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt')

tasks={}


def func_assign_job(row):
    '''A function executed on each row of the df dataframe.
    I want for each row the job string to be unique'''    
    tasks['job_{0}{1}'.format(str(row.name),str(row.time))] = cron.new(command='python crontab_example1.py')

df.apply(func_assign_job, axis=1)
```

Comment: Yes, using a dictionary worked!